# How to make separate method for three almost identical methods

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .net core application. and I have this fitler function:

```
private IQueryable<Alert> GetAlerts(Expression<Func<Alert, bool>> filter, bool includeDone = false)
{
    var query = _patientDbContext.Alerts
        .Where(filter);

    if (!includeDone)
    {
        query = query.Where(i => !i.IsDone);
    }

    query = query.OrderBy(i => i.Deadline);

    return query;
}
```

and I have three functions that are using the filter function, like this:

```
public async Task<List<Alert>> GetAllAlertsForOrganisation(int organisationId, DateTime? beginDate, DateTime? endDate)
{
    return await GetAlerts(i => i.OrganisationId == organisationId && (endDate == null || i.CreatedAt <= endDate) &&
        (beginDate == null || i.CreatedAt >= beginDate)).ToListAsync();           
}

public async Task<List<Alert>> GetAlertsForParticipantOfOrganisation(int organisationId, Guid participantId, DateTime? beginDate, DateTime? endDate)
{
   return await GetAlerts(i => i.OrganisationId == organisationId && (endDate == null || i.CreatedAt <= endDate) &&
        (beginDate == null || i.CreatedAt >= beginDate)).ToListAsync();          
}

public async Task<int> GetAllAlertsForOrganisationCount(int organisationId, DateTime? beginDate, DateTime? endDate)
{
    return await GetAlerts(i => i.OrganisationId == organisationId && (endDate == null || i.CreatedAt <= endDate) &&
       (beginDate == null || i.CreatedAt >= beginDate)).CountAsync();         
}
```

But they are almost identical. So is it possible to write this shorter?

Comment: Well you can remove the `Guid participantId` parameter from the third snippet. The method is not using it. Then the second and third methods are doing the same thing, which means one of them could be removed.

Comment: I mean specially the endDate and beginDate

Comment: Well you could move the date parameters into the `GetAlerts` method since they are used everywhere.

Comment: yes, can you give example

Comment: You could create a new method that would return alerts for organization as `IQueryable<Alert>` and then use this method in the other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `Guid participantId` parameter from `GetAlertsForParticipantOfOrganisation`, since the method is not using this parameter. Then you can remove it since its the same as `GetAllAlertsForOrganisation`.

With the above in mind, you could create another method that returns `IQueryable<Alert>`and does the filtering repeated by your 3 methods:

```
public IQueryable<Alert> GetAllAlerts(int organisationId, DateTime? beginDate, DateTime? endDate)
{
    return GetAlerts(i => i.OrganisationId == organisationId &&
        (endDate == null || i.CreatedAt <= endDate) &&
        (beginDate == null || i.CreatedAt >= beginDate));
}
```

Then you can use the same logic in your other methods:

```
public async Task<List<Alert>> GetAllAlertsForOrganisation(int organisationId, DateTime? beginDate, DateTime? endDate)
{
    return await GetAllAlerts(organisationId, beginDate, endDate).ToListAsync();
}

public async Task<int> GetAllAlertsForOrganisationCount(int organisationId, DateTime? beginDate, DateTime? endDate)
{
    return await GetAllAlerts(organisationId, beginDate, endDate).CountAsync();
}
```